# in this jquery-ui example, what is the expected json from the server?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

in [this example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple-remote) should you be returning an array in json or a single comma seperated string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the requested link, and it returns JSON:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/search.php?term=t

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code (you can view source farther down on the page - have to expand it), it looks like it returns a JSON format.

```
function(request, response) {
    $.getJSON("search.php", {
        term: extractLast(request.term)
    }, response);
},
```

Another way of seeing what you need is use the developer tools in your browsers (or the Firebug plug-in in Firefox) to see what is being transferred between the server and host as you type.

Comment: @ooo - That's why I suggested using the developer tools in your browser. You can examine the request and response data sent to and returned from the server, respectively. This is good knowledge to have in the future when this question may come up again.